# Why is my datagrid only populating one row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

It's going through the foreach loop multiple times with multiple values but only populates the grid with one row.

```
        string textLines;
        string[] textLine;

        textLines = scannedGuid.Text;

        textLine = textLines.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        DataSet ds2 = null; 
        Database db2 = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("CouponConnectionString");

        Database db2 = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
        foreach (string s in textLine)
        {

            try
            {

                DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_Guid_p");
                db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
                ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }

        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds2;
        DataBind();
```

Comment: What is textLine (i.e., List<string>, etc)?

Comment: I have added additional code to show the textLine.

Comment: @Tim, lol posting on both questions. This has to be some kind of homework. SkyDawg33 check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670089/how-can-i-loop-through-an-array-and-populate-a-datagrid your classmate is asking the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this code

```
            DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_Guid_p");
            db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
            ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
```

Is returning one row.

Just because you're calling it multiple times, doesn't mean there are multiple records.  You are overwriting the value of the variable everything your loop executes.

Perhaps you can put the results of your dataset into an object (make a class that represents the results), then when you loop, add each result object to a list, then bind that list to the grid.

An example:

```
    List<MyCustomerClassForTheReturnedValues> values = new List<MyCustomClassForTheReturnedValues>();

    foreach (string s in textLine)
    {


            DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_Guid_p");
            db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
            MyCustomClassForTheReturnedValues x = new MyCustomClassForTheReturnedValues(db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2));
            values.Add(x);


    }


    DataGrid1.DataSource = values;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this will be one DB lookup per entry. This could be very inefficient, depending on your architecture. If you can pass the entire string of guids in separate them in your sproc, and pass back the entire list, it will be one call, which is much better.

Comment: Agree with Schroedingers Cat.  Was answering without re-architecting everything :)

Comment: Which is right - I just think there may be more significant issues underlying this that are worth addressing too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are overwriting your dataset each time, so when you complete the loop, you only have the final dataset, which I presume contains just one row.

What are you trying to do?

Rather - you need to put all of the parameters into one SP to get all of them, OR combine your muliptle datasets into one data structure to populate the data grid.