# How can I loop through an array and populate a datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

Here's the scenario:

I have a multiline text box that I'm reading each line into an array. I'm then looping through that array and sending each value to the stored proc one by one inside the loop and getting a status returned to tell whether it's valid or not.

The issue is I believe I'm overwriting the dataset variable and only populating the datagrid with the last value I retrieve. Is there a better way to achieve what im trying to do? If so, please explain.

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textLines;
        string[] textLine;

        textLines = scannedCode.Text;

        textLine = textLines.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        DataSet ds = null;
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
        DataSet ds2 = null; 
        Database db2 = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");

        foreach (string s in textLine)
        {
            try
            {
                DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_InfoByID_p");
                db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
                ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
                DataGrid1.DataSource = ds2;
                DataBind();

             }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: This looks just like [Why is my datagrid only populating one row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668009/why-is-my-datagrid-only-populating-one-row).  You two work for the same company?  Reading the same book?  Taking the same class? :)

Comment: is this a HW? I did saw quite the same question asked 2h ago [question link is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668009/why-is-my-datagrid-only-populating-one-row) p.s. lol @Tim @bemused

Comment: Trey do you need to keep the records in a datatable or can you just simply add the results from the stored procedure right to the datagrid. If so then use something like DataGrid1.Rows.Add(Your row)

Answer (score 1):

Create a DataTable outside and in your for loop add your returned row .

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

///...Add known columns here

Inside for loop add rows to table . After for loop bind table at once.

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textLines;
        string[] textLine;

        textLines = scannedCode.Text;

        textLine = textLines.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        DataSet ds = null;
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
        DataSet ds2 = null; 
        Database db2 = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ///...Add known columns here
        foreach (string s in textLine)
        {
            try
            {
                DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_InfoByID_p");
                db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
                DataRow myNewRow = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2).tables[0].rows[0];
                dt.Rows.Add(myNewRow);

             }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


               DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
                DataBind();


    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do I go about creating the datatable and implementing it with my code?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is possible to merge two dataSets by using the DataSet.Merge method.  It means, that you should create a new DataSet outside of the loop and then merge it to a DataSet created by the stored procedure.  One more solution is to copy rows from one DataSet to another using the Table's ImportRow method.  The latter solution looks better for me.  Here is some sample code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable;
...  

ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
for(int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i ++)
dt.ImportRow(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]);

...
DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DataTable obj_Tb=new DataTable();
  obj_Tb.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
   .  //Add Columns as your requirement
   .
   .

foreach (string s in textLine)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRow objrow=obj_Tb.NewRow();
                DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_InfoByID_p");
                db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
                ds2= db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
          objrow["ColumnName"]=ds2.Table[0].Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"].tostring();
                //Add Values to all columns as requirement
                obj_Tb.Rows.Add(objrow);

             }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
}
              DataGrid1.DataSource = obj_Tb;
              DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem was that you are binding the grid on EACH iteration, else nothing wrong with the code. So rather than:

```
    foreach (string s in textLine)
    {
        try
        {
            DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_InfoByID_p");
            db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
            ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
            DataGrid1.DataSource = ds2;
            DataBind();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

do this:

```
    foreach (string s in textLine)
    {
        try
        {
            DbCommand command2 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_InfoByID_p");
            db2.AddInParameter(command2, "@pGuid", DbType.String, s);
            ds2 = db2.ExecuteDataSet(command2);
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds2;
    DataBind();
```

However, since you're doing looping on the same functionality, for optimizing i suggest:

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcName", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter submitParam = new SqlParameter("@pGuid", SqlDbType.String);

    //use SqlDbType.Bit if  you are returning true/false.      
    SqlParameter returParameter = new SqlParameter("@ReturnedParam", SqlDbType.String);  
    returParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    connection.Open();

    foreach (string s in textLine)
    {
            returnString.Value = s;            
            command.Parameters.Clear(); 
            command.Parameters.Add(submitParam); 
            command.Parameters.Add(returParameter);         

            try
            {                
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    store the returned string in DataTable, BindingList<string> or any, but this is how to retrieve it:
                Convert.ToString(Command.Parameters["@ReturnedParam"].Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ;;
            }
    }

    connection.Close();

    Do the grid binding here
```